# Draw sprite on Body - camera View Port and resize

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm drawing sprites uppon bodies, with this method (inside my body wrapper):

```
private void drawBaseSprite(Batch batch){
        Sprite baseSprite = this.getBaseSprite();

        Vector3 bodyPixelPos = camera.project(new Vector3(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y, 0));

        // TODO: 17/11/16 Review this
        float w = scale * (baseSprite.getTexture().getWidth())/camera.zoom;
        float h = scale * (baseSprite.getTexture().getHeight())/camera.zoom ;

        baseSprite.setSize(w,h);
        baseSprite.setOrigin(w/2, h/2);
        baseSprite.setPosition(bodyPixelPos.x -w/2, bodyPixelPos.y - h/2);
        baseSprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);


        baseSprite.draw(batch);
    }
```

Everything is good, until I try resizing the windows. Well, I'm following this resize logic (implements Screen) :

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    stage.camera.setToOrtho(false, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT *width/(float)height, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
}
```

Before resize:
[image: before resize]
After resize (larger width):
[image: after resize (larger width)]

I find this absurd because this:

```
        float w = scale * (baseSprite.getTexture().getWidth())/camera.zoom;
        float h = scale * (baseSprite.getTexture().getHeight())/camera.zoom ;
```

doesn't change, while the images are x-scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in understanding that your problem is the image not staying on top of the body?

If so, the reason why it doesn't is that you are setting the size of the image relative to the camera, not to the body it is supposed to cover. When your camera's zoom is changed, you adjust the size of the image, but not the body, and they get out of sync.

I would recommend changing your logic such that the image height/width are determined purely by the body, and your body is scaled based on the camera zoom.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I tracked the sprite dimensions :

Gdx.app.log(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"w: "+w+" h: "+h);

and they don't change, even after resize, because camera's zoom doesn't change neither (only view port is changed).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this solved my problem, but I still don't deeply-know why.

```
private void drawBaseSprite(Batch batch){
        Sprite baseSprite = this.getBaseSprite();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        float someScale = 0.1f;

        float w = scale * (baseSprite.getTexture().getWidth())/camera.zoom *someScale;
        float h = scale * (baseSprite.getTexture().getHeight())/camera.zoom *someScale;


        Vector3 bodyPixelPos = camera.project(new Vector3(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y, 0))
                .scl(someScale*camera.viewportHeight/(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20f)).sub(w/2, h/2, 0);

        baseSprite.setSize(w,h);
        baseSprite.setOrigin(w/2, h/2);
        baseSprite.setPosition(bodyPixelPos.x, bodyPixelPos.y);
        baseSprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);

        baseSprite.draw(batch);
    }
```